# LINQ to SQL - custom propery

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

How could I add a custom propery to a LINQ2SQL class. if I have 2 properties "filename" and "filepath" and I'd like to return a property such as "fullFilePath".

thank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546176.aspx) - Adding Business Logic By Using Partial Methods (LINQ to SQL)

```
public partial class myLinqClass {
   public string fullFilePath {
      get { return this.filepath + this.filename; } //clean this up as appropriate
   }
}
```